# Generate contour lines for big DEMs and import into PostGis

Tags: postgis, contour, elevation

I've downloaded the SRTM DEM files for most of Europe, from both 3arc_v4.1 and 1arc_v3 versions. The first comes in 5x5 degrees tiles, the latter in 1x1. I can stitch them together with `gdalbuildvrt` into a huge file (208801x90001 pixels, according to `gdalinfo`). So far so good; I can even generate terrain coloring, hill and slope shading without a problem (except time, of course).

What I can't do is to generate contour lines for it. `gdal_contour` either runs out of RAM (8GiB) or reaches the ESRI Shapefile file limit (2GiB, I think). I can generate shapefiles for each individual tile and then run `shp2pgsql` to import it, but the problem is at the tile limit: The contour lines from one tile cross the correlative one from the next tile. For example:

http://grulicueva.homenet.org/~mdione/Elevation/#14/45.0000/15.0000

So the question is: is it possible to import such big datasets, in particular directly to PostGis? if not, is it possible to stitch the individual ones before importing into PostGis?

Comment: If you use raster2pgsql you can load multiple tiles into one raster coverage. Then, you could use something like [the query here](https://smathermather.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/proper-abuse-of-a-database-postgresql-postgis-arcgis/) to select 9 sets of tiles, contour the middle one, move on to the next one, etc. It probably won't be very fast, but it is doable.

Comment: Well, I could also generate 9-tile virtual tiles with `gdalbuildvrt` to replace importing the raster files to PostGIS, and then "generate the contour for the middle one".